# SteamVR Controller Rotation to float

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, htc-vive

I want to controll the steering of a motorcycle by tilting a SteamVR-Controller left or right.

What I tried is:

```
private SteamVR_Controller.Device controller;
public Vector3 angle { get { return controller.transform.rot.eulerAngles.x; } }
public float steerInput = 0f;

void Inputs (){
steerInput = steerInput * angle;
}
```

I get the following Error: Cannot implicitly convert type `float' to`UnityEngine.Vector3'

Do you have an idea to fix it?
Greetings from germany :)

Comment: Which line are you getting that error?

Comment: In the public Vector 3 angle

Answer (score 1):

Your `angle` variable is a type of `Vector3`.

The `controller.transform.rot.eulerAngles.x` property is a type of `float`.

You get:

> Error: Cannot implicitly convert type float' toUnityEngine.Vector3':

because you are tying to return `controller.transform.rot.eulerAngles.x` which is a `float` in a property that is `Vector3`.

Return `controller.transform.rot.eulerAngles` instead since `eulerAngles`  is `Vector3`.

```
private SteamVR_Controller.Device controller;
public Vector3 angle { get { return controller.transform.rot.eulerAngles;} }
public float steerInput = 0f;
```

Note that the-same thing applies to the `steerInput = steerInput * angle;` but in reversed this time. You can't convert `Vector3` to `float` and have to fix that too. I can't tell what exactly you are doing there but you must fix it too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this leads to the same mistake :(

Comment: I think that's what OP meant. I describes that in my answer. Have no idea what OP is trying to do with `steerInput = steerInput * angle;` but he's assigning wrong datatype to `steerInput`.

Comment: Mistake is in the same line. And it would'nt solve my problem. Because I need the x rotation. In other words: The X Rotation of the controller should increase or decrease the value of steerInput. Any ideas? Seems like vector 3 and float can't be combined in this way